# How to store parseObject.getString() into a member variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform

I am having a weird issue with ParseObject.

I have a class that manages data with 1 member variables.

```
String partnerEmail = "default@email.com";
```

I try to retrieve an email address from parseObject with:

```
object.getString("partnerEmail");
```

and I want to save it into my member variable (partnerEmail) but it never saves it.
Here is full code of the method to read the partner email:

```
public String findEmail( ) {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("myTable");
    query.whereEqualTo("email", user.getEmail() );
    query.getFirstInBackground( new GetCallback<ParseObject> ( ) {
        public void done( ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if ( object != null ) {
                partnerEmail = object.getString("partnerEmail");
                Log.d("inside", partnerEmail);
            }
        }
    });

    Log.d("outside", partnerEmail);
    return partnerEmail;
}
```

every time I run this code I see in logs:
inside: example@mail.com **(which is correct!)**
outisde: default@mail.com **(which is the default)**

Any ideas why this happens or why I cant store the correct email inside my member variable? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are misunderstanding how a callback works - have you figured this out yet or do you still need help?

Comment: Yes, thanks everyone for help. I am new to all this but I already figured out the problem and all I did is have a handler and wait until I get my information then do my thing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to getFirstInBackground is a nonblocking-api, which contained a callback function. Done will be called after the thread(request for this query) finished, so that the outside-log will print first and then the inside-log.

If you want a blocking-api.

```
public String findEmail( ) {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("myTable");
    query.whereEqualTo("email", user.getEmail() );
    try {
        ParseObject object = query.getFirst();
        partnerEmail = object.getString("partnerEmail");
        Log.d("inside", partnerEmail);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //error
    }
    Log.d("outside", partnerEmail);
    return partnerEmail;
}
```

or let callback as an argument in findEmail, done will be called when it finished.

Answer (score 0):

Use **break** keyword after Log.d("inside", partnerEmail); this line. Something like this

```
if ( object != null ) {
    partnerEmail = object.getString("partnerEmail");
    Log.d("inside", partnerEmail);
    break;
}
```

Comment: I can't break and return doesn't help either =[

Answer (score 0):

you have not initialization inside method your string.
try to this way like.

```
public String findEmail() {
    final String partnerEmail = null;
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("myTable");
    query.whereEqualTo("email", user.getEmail());
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // success
                if (object != null) {
                    partnerEmail = object.getString("partnerEmail");
                    Log.d("inside", partnerEmail);
                }
            } else {
                // error
            }
        }
    });

    Log.d("outside", partnerEmail);
    return partnerEmail;
}
```

now check your `inside` & `outside` log.